# Python how to erase a file once it's opened with "with"

Tags: python, file

I'm saving the loop iteration number of my script to a checkpoint file:

```
with open('checkpoint.txt', 'w') as checkpoint_file:
    for i range(1000):
        //do stuff
        checkpoint_file.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

This will write a new line in my file for each iteration.

What I would like is to have only one line with the last iteration number when I interrupt the script, so I would like to erase the content of "checkpoint.txt" file, and then write my iteration number on the first line (or directly replace the first line if this is possible).

I know that if I close the file and then open it again with `with open('checkpoint.txt', 'w')` its content will be erased, but I'd like to keep the file opened if possible for efficiency.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete only the content of file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126037/how-to-delete-only-the-content-of-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`seek`ing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) before each `write` (and switch to line buffering to avoid the need to `flush` separately) will do this:

```
# buffering=1 means you automatically flush after writing a line
with open('checkpoint.txt', 'w', buffering=1) as checkpoint_file:
    for i in range(1000):
        //do stuff
        checkpoint_file.seek(0)  # Seek back to beginning of file so next write replaces contents
        checkpoint_file.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: I would add a `truncate` to handle the case where next line is shorter than previous one...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: In the general case, yes, that would be correct. In this particular case, the checkpoint is a monotonically increasing number, so each newly written string will always be as long as, or longer than, the previous output, making it unnecessary to explicitly `truncate` (barring the off chance that you're using a text encoding so weird that the different numeric digits produced by stringifying an `int` encode to a variable number of bytes; if you know of such an encoding, let me know, and it'll be yet one more computer-related factoid to torture people with :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Seek to the start of the file before each write. 
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek